# redirect with .htaccess rewrite rule to different folder on my server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I have been trying to redirect to a different folder with .htaccess when I hit a domain.

Here's my .htaccess redirect rule, can you tell me where am I wrong?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?racereadymotorsports.in$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /raceready/$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?annelies-slabbynck.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /annelies/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So, what I want is, if someone visits racereadymotorsports.in, they redirect to /raceready/ directory
and on the other hand if they visit to annelies-slabbynck.com, they should redirect to /annelies/ directory

At present, this redirects twice for annelies-slabbynck.com which means that, I end up with:
http://www.annelies-slabbynck.com/annelies/annelies/ as my final url

I am running a shared hosting and do not have access to add a new configuration.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `[OR]` flag and reproduce the same conditions with the other rule. Maybe something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?racereadymotorsports.in$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /raceready/$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?annelies-slabbynck.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /annelies/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or better yet, you can use these conditions instead:    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?racereadymotorsports.in$ 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/raceready/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/raceready/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /raceready/$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?annelies-slabbynck.com$ 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/annelies/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/annelies/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /annelies/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that the `R=301` flag in your second rule redirects the browser, unlike the first rule which only internally rewrites the request.